# How to display a custom made table on a new sheet automatically at creation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I made table on the main worksheet and did some customization to it. Is there a way such that when I create the new sheet (sheet 2, sheet 3 etc) to automatically display that table, but without any of the entries on the sheet 1?

What I want to do is to emulate a catalog with grades for a student on a sheet. When I create a new sheet (a new empty catalog for a student) I want the empty table.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you mean to “display that table, but without any of the entries”.

Comment: @DourHighArch Say that I made this table https://i.imgur.com/JpXQKu5.png on the `Sheet1`. When I create `Sheet2` I want it to be o the exact same position with the exact columns names, but with no contents in its cells